# Web Client timeout while downloading photos from external link

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to download 10 photos from an external link e.g http://images.net/images/20159178574IMG_0843.jpg

I am reading a text file on my drive and putting it on a list here is the code

```
List < string > lines = new List < string > ();
using(StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fileName)) 
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        lines.Add(line);
    }
}

foreach(string s in lines) 
{
    getthefile(s, System.DateTime.Now.Hour + System.DateTime.Now.Minute + System.DateTime.Now.Second + ".jpg");
}

private void getthefile(string filename, string filenamesave) 
{
    if (checkurl(filename)) 
    {

        string filepath = @
        "D:\files" + "\\Photos\\" + filenamesave;
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFile(filename, filepath);
    }
}

private bool checkurl(string url) 
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    switch ((int) response.StatusCode) 
    {
        case 200:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Now the first photo on the list gets downloaded but when the loop moves to the next photo it gets stuck for about 2 minutes and throws a ***timeout exception*** I tried making a new list to see if it the error occurs again but sadly it throws the same error.

is there something wrong with my code or the server hosting the *IIS*?

thank you

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code when you post. I strongly suspect it isn't that badly indented in Visual Studio. Additionally, what does `checkurl` do? (Now would also be a good time to learn about .NET naming conventions and start following them... you might want to look at `File.ReadAllLines` too.)

Comment: sorry for the clumsy formatting actually i did try File.ReadAllLines but the same errror occurs.

Comment: No, don't add the code in a comment - put it in the *question*.

Comment: Rather than apologising for the clumsy formatting, why not just fix it?

Comment: there i just approved the edit suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is in the `checkurl` method, which doesn't dispose of the `WebResponse` that it gets - that means the connection pool associated with that host has effectively "lost" that connection until the `WebResponse` gets finalized. Basically, always use a `using` statement with `WebResponse` objects.

Aside from that, it's not clear why you want to make two requests for each URL anyway - nor whether your `checkurl` is *actually* going to return `false` when you encounter an error, rather than throwing an exception. I'd just skip the `checkurl` test, try to download the file, and handle any exceptions thrown by `WebClient` instead.

Comment: thank you for the reply the checkurl was the culprit